# Trying to rename repeated columns in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of duplicate columns in my DataFrame (named as `df` here in the code) and I am trying to rename duplicate columns by adding a number in the end. For example:

If there are two columns named `col`, then I want two columns named `col1` and `col2`.

But this code gives two column names as `col1` and `col1` again.

```py
for col in duplicate_col:
    counter = 1 
    for col2 in df.columns:
        if(col2==col):
        df.rename(columns={col2:col2+str(counter)},inplace=True)
        counter = counter+1
```

Comment: a column is at most twice in the df?

Comment: no some column names are more than twice.